# Bind external js file after load of single element?

Tags: javascript

I've been looking into initiating an external js document (such as a jquery plugin in exmample) after the loading of a specific element, such as an html video. I'm struggling to implement it and would love some help, especially since I haven't been able to find much on this.

My initial idea was to use the `DOMContentLoaded` event, but I failed to execute it on load of a specific element as if I understand correctly it is waiting for ALL the content in the DOM to load.

So my second attempt looked like a snippet I found

```
// creates script on page
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = "src";
$('body').append(script);

//binds on load of element (I think?)
$(function(){
    $(".video").bind('load', ...Not sure where to go from here.)
});
```

And that has been the full extent of my research skills combined with my javascript skills. It'd be great if in addition to a correct answer I could get a brief breakdown of the `how it works`. Thanks saints!

Comment: so, what do you want to do with this? why don't you just load the external js when the document loading? - why the the external js must be initiated after an element loaded?

Comment: @OkiErieRinaldi because in the case of a video of photo, and a plugin that should take effect after it is loaded I'd like it to load when the image or video finishes which could be either before or after the rest of the document. I would mind some resources on loading after the document loads though. Thanks :)

Comment: what kind of plug in do you have? what will the plugin do after you load it? I'm sorry, I don't understand -_-

Comment: Well I'm looking for something more general so i can implement it in future situations as well, but in this case I am working on a project that was just handed to me that was in 3 different developers hands before, is a total mess and the company didnt charge the client enough to budget a full re-dev. With that said the plugin used positions elements relative to other elements and is a javascript alternative to css responsive development from my understanding, the issue I run into now is the plugin fires before a video element loads which causes it to be positioned too high in the document.

Comment: does the plugin have a trigger?

Comment: The plugin can be triggered for each element it is applied to, most with `$(document).ready` which, based on its behavior is when the elements are all loaded but not necessarily all the content, i.e. the video has not yet sized itself and begun loading at that point.